# kwicks with divs

Tags: jquery, html, kwicks

The html of this script is made with list items
http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=kwicks

Where can I find a script like this that works with divs, so I can make the inactive images darker and the active one normal like you see here:
https://www.bnpparibasfortis.be/portal/start.asp

Comment: The reason `li`'s are used is that it really is a list of options. A `div` should really be used mainly for actual page division, so for example as a container for your main content, menu, footer and header.

Can you not change your code to use an `ul` in stead of `div`'s?

Comment: Use the css3 opacity-property

Comment: A `div` gives no more or less flexibility than an `li`. There is nothing that you could do to a `div` that you could not do to an `li`. You should try to write correct semantic html at all times, and that is why kwiks is written that way.

Comment: good point, I changed it back to li, and it's work the same way, thanks

Comment: Just a heads up in case anyone comes across this - Kwicks has a major new update out (v2.0.0) that supports more flexible markup structures (among other enhancements).  It also has a new home now: http://devsmash.com/projects/kwicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css opacity makes it bright, not dark
but I've got the solution
I changed rule 28 in the kwicks script from

```
var kwicks = container.children('li');
```

to

```
var kwicks = container.children('div');
```

This is the html:

```
<div style="background: url(thumb-58-madagascar.jpg) no-repeat scroll center top;">
    <div class="inactive"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div#accordion-slider{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
div#accordion-slider div{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    float: left;
    width: 165px;
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 230px;
}
div#accordion-slider div.inactive {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
div#accordion-slider div.active div.inactive {
    background: none;
}
```